# Java calling method and moving object across the screen using timer class

Tags: java

I am trying to get my actionPerformed to loop through a method from another class, using the Timer class, by doing so this will repaint my object and appear as though it is moving across the screen.
I have added a System.out.println statement to see if the actionPerformed is firing. The text is being displayed but the object doesn't seem to move across the screen, not sure what i'm doing wrong :\ Can anyone shed some light on whats not right?

//this is my ball class, which i have made into an array. The timer.start() is in the constuctor

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < bl.length; i++)
    {
    bl[i].move();
    System.out.println("Fired");
    repaint();
    }
}
```

//this is my move class to move the object across the screen, x=0 and move =5.

```
public void move()
{
    x = x + move;
}
```

Comment: Are you using Java or Javascript?

Comment: Seems like Java. Your question definitely needs more explanation/source code. What is it that you try to move?

Comment: trying to move a paint component, fillOval(x, y, 50, 50)

Comment: did you forget to addActionListener()... it happens sometimes... post full running code

Comment: This has nothing to do with the usage of the Timer class.

Answer (score 1):

In your `move()` method, you try to add a variable called `move` to `x` but `move` is neither defined nor passed. Try this:

```
bl[i].move(5,0);

public int move(int move,int x)
{
x += move;
return x;
}
```

EDIT: Speaking of which, `x` is not defined or passed either. I have edited the code.